# Установил Arch на VIrtualBox, теперь не могу подключиться к инету

Tags: linux, archlinux

Поставил арч по инструкции с вики, аконец всё прошло успешно арч стал, но дальше всё остановилось по причине отсутствия подключения с инетом, пока грузился с фрчизо инет был как только загрузил новую систему установленную на виртуалку инет пропал

Comment: А на новой системе вы вообще не забыли настроить интернет?

Comment: я ничего не настраивал, да и особо нечего настраивать кажется, арч очень минималестичен

Comment: Хоть каких то данных добавте `ip a` `ip r`

Comment: @Gybernaty ну вот поэтому интернета и нет. Вперёд в Arch Wiki читать как сеть настраивать

Comment: глупый вопрос, но переустанавливать пробовали? я почему-то уверен что вы где-то допустили ошибку во время установки.

Comment: Если что, как раз в VirtualBox можно настроить интернет, даже если забыл при установке поставить нужные пакеты

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно снова загрузится с установочного диска, сразу примонтировать корень с уже установленной программой /mnt. Потом Arch-root и systemctl enable dhcpcd@enp3s0.
Отмонтировать и загрузиться с установленной системы.

Answer (score 0):

Выполните `systemctl start dhcpcd` от root

Comment: сервис не найден

Answer (score 0):

я знаю что у вас.

это детская проблема.

Когда выполняли команду `pacstrap` при установке забыли установить `dhcpcd`.

Вам нужно будет заново инициировать установку и на шаге где нужно установить программы можно сделать как у [меня](https://github.com/akimdi/wiki/blob/master/docs/archlinux.md#%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-base-%D0%B8-base-devel).

И тогда после установки можно уже будет делать что вам и посоветовал [Gravit](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1097071/182065)

[А именно](https://github.com/akimdi/wiki/blob/master/docs/archlinux.md#%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-dhcp-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA)

`sudo systemctl enable dhcpcd@enp3s0`

`sudo systemctl start dhcpcd@enp3s0`

Comment: киты медленно всклывают

Comment: в общем при установке по твоей инструкции выдал ошибку target not fond по hdhcpd и intel-ucore  @Ivan

Comment: failed to install packages to new root  и дальше при команде arch-chroot /mnt  >  failed to run commend /bin/bash: no such fine or dir...

Comment: никто бы у Вас не всплывал, если бы Вы хоть немного были внимательны. 
Конечно будет выдавать ошибку target not fond по hdhcpd и intel-ucore. 
Вы пишите intel-ucore а нужно untel-ucode. Тоже самое и с другими пакетом. 
Потому что Вы не пишите название пакета. У меня в инструкции не так написано. Перечитайте внимательно и напишите правильно. Тогда вопросов у Вас станет меньше. 
Честно даже не хочется помогать после такого.

Comment: Ладно не кипятись у тебя СУПЕР инструкция, просто я чуть не в себе был и долго не спал